# Attribution of translated quotations

Tags: discussion, quotations, translations

Is it not policy on this site that quoted matter should be attributed to its author? If the quotation has been translated from its original language, does the translator deserve attribution as well? When translations are quoted without naming a translator, as in [this question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/how-do-people-eat-in-the-library-of-babel) or [this answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/239/how-many-sailors-from-odysseus-crew-survived-the-odyssey/241#241), is it fair to assume that we are reading the poster's own translation from the Spanish of Borges or the Ancient Greek of Homer?

Comment: It really should be. What translation you are using can drastically impact answers. I think i did this at the beginning of the sites history, then i got lazy. I'll try to start doing this again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Translated works are as much the work of the translator as the author. It's especially important, because if *you* translate something to ask about it, answerers need to know.

Translations also impact answers, rather significantly. Differences in translations, and choices made during the process, always distort away some meaning, no matter the translator.

Cite both.